# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigcup\limits_{k \ge n} A_k$ of $A_n:=$ open circle with radius $=1 $ and center $(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}, 0)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, analysis, limits

$A_n:=$ open circle with radius $=1 $ and center $(\frac{(-1)^n}{n}, 0)$.

What's

a) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigcup\limits_{k \ge n} A_k$ and

b)  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\bigcap\limits_{k \ge n} A_k$?

For b) I would say the open circle with radius $1$ and center $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : for a) the closed circle with radius 1, center $(0,0)$ **without** the points : $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$

for b) as you said.

Sketch of proof of a) : let $(x,y)$ a point such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $(x,y)\notin \{(0,-1),(0,1)\} $. The more difficult point is if $x^2+y^2=1$ ; in this last case, we have $|x|>0$ (we suppose wlog $x>0$ in the sequel). Then if we denote $\mathcal{C}_{n}$ the open circle of center $\big((-1)^n\frac{1}{n},0\big)$, I claim that there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, 
\begin{align*}
 (x,y)\in \mathcal{C}_{2n} &\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad  \bigg(x-\frac{1}{2n}\bigg)^2 + y^2< 1 \\
& \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad  \bigg(x-\frac{1}{2n}\bigg)^2 + 1-x^2< 1 \\
& \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad  \bigg(x-\frac{1}{2n}\bigg)^2 -x^2< 0 \\
& \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad   x>\frac{1}{2n} 
\end{align*}
You have just to take $N=[\frac{1}{2x}]+1$.

The case $x^2+y^2< 1$ is obtain with the same techniques.

Comment: Can you explain a)? @Netchaiev

Comment: @dirkpra see my edit

Comment: Ok I understand what you did but why do you start with $(x, y) \in C_{2n}$?

Comment: @dirkpra because the distance of $(x,y)$ to the centrum $(\frac{1}{2n},0)$ is $<1$ (line 1 of the system).